# Insert Overwrite Partitioned Table in BigQuery dynamically

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I just need a way on Bigquery to insert overwrite data from my SELECT statement to my partitioned target table dynamically, meaning, if the select has data for a partition that already exists in my target, it should overwrite it, if the partition doesnt exist for that load_date it should create a new parition and load data there.

This is simply done in impala or hive using the syntax (and setting the dynamic config to true):

insert overwrite table table_name (partition_field)
select * from source

What is the alternative in BigQuery? From what i've seen it can't be done this simply using DML

Answer (score 1):

You can take inspiration from [DBT usage in the insert overwrite option](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/bigquery-configs#the-insert_overwrite-strategy)

```
      -- generated script to merge partitions into `project`.`dataset`.`table`
      declare dbt_partitions_for_replacement array<date>;   
      
        -- 1. create a temp table
    create or replace table `project`.`dataset`.`table__dbt_tmp`
    partition by <partition field>
    cluster by ....
    OPTIONS(
...    )
    as ( <YOUR QUERY>);

      -- 2. define partitions to update
      set (dbt_partitions_for_replacement) = (
          select as struct
              array_agg(distinct <partition field>)
          from `project`.`dataset`.`table__dbt_tmp`
      );

      -- 3. run the merge statement
      

    merge into `project`.`dataset`.`table` as DBT_INTERNAL_DEST
        using (
        select * from `project`.`dataset`.`table__dbt_tmp`
      ) as DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE
        on FALSE

    when not matched by source
         and DBT_INTERNAL_DEST.<partition_field> in unnest(dbt_partitions_for_replacement) 
        then delete

    when not matched then insert
        (<list of fields>)
    values
        (<list of fields>)

;

      -- 4. clean up the temp table
      drop table if exists `project`.`dataset`.`table__dbt_tmp`
```

Comment: Thanks, it just looks like a lot of work to do a simple task

Comment: Totally agree. I discovered this mechanism with DBT. I'm unable to write it from scratch by myself!!